# Views showing quizzes and content sharing taxonomy term

Tags: views

I have a Drupal 9 site, with a lot of quizzes and content pages. Both have the same vocabulary attached (Category), and want to create a view showing all quizzes and nodes sharing same category.

Is that possible, or is it better to create a custom page and do the magic my self ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating using views.
Create a view with view settings set to `taxonomy`.
Go to relationship and add the taxonomy field that is added to your node.
Add another field in the relationship `Taxonomy term referenced from your-taxonomy-field` and select relationship from dropdown.

Add title and taxonomy name in the field and you can group using format settings,
selecting the field you want to group.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell what is their type? Custom Entity?